# How to extract from FAT16 filesystem image in Python

Tags: python, fat, fat16

I have a image which is FAT (16 bit), I want to parser the image to file, so that i can get the files in image.

Comment: Probably not. What is the question?

Comment: I want to get the files in FAT in python

Answer (score 1):

As far as reading a FAT32 filesystem image in Python goes, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32) has all the detail you need to write a read-only implementation.

[Construct](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) may be of some use. Looks like they have an example for FAT16 (https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/master/construct/examples/formats/filesystem/fat16.py) which you could try extending.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was in a similar situation, where I needed FAT12/16/32 support in Python. Searching the web you can find various implementations (such as [maxpat78/FATtools](https://github.com/maxpat78/FATtools), [em-/grasso](https://github.com/em-/grasso) or [hisahi/PyFAT12](https://github.com/hisahi/PyFAT12)).

None of those libraries were available via PyPI at the time or were lacking features I needed so (full disclosure) I decided to write my own but I'll try to sum it up as objectively as possible:

[pyfatfs](https://pypi.org/project/pyfatfs/) supports FAT12, FAT16 as well as FAT32 including VFAT (long file names) and can be installed via pip as a pure Python package (no native dependencies such as [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/) needed and/or included). It implements functionality for [PyFilesystem2](https://www.pyfilesystem.org/), a framework for basic file operations across different filesystem implementations (SSH, AWS S3, OSFS host directory pass-through, …). Aside from that pyfatfs can also be used standalone (without PyFilesystem2) in case you need to make more low-level operations (manipulating directory/file entries, changing disk attributes, formatting disks/images, manipulating FAT, etc.).

For instance, to copy files from a diskette image to your host via PyFilesystem2:

```
import fs
fat_fs = fs.open_fs("fat://my_diskette.img")  # Open disk image
host_fs = fs.open_fs("osfs:///tmp") # Open '/tmp' directory on host
fs.copy.copy_dir(fat_fs, "/", host_fs, "/") # Copy all files from the disk image to the host_fs filesystem (/tmp directory on host)
```